# Can't find a module saved in another subdirectory

Tags: python

I have a Python file that I'm trying to import into a session. The file structure looks like the following

```
-object_detection
--__init__.py
--export_inference_graphy.py
--protos 
---__init__.py
---pipeline_pb2.py
```

From the export_inference_graph file, I'm trying to import pipeline_pb2.

However, I get the following error.

```
from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-60-76f12fdd6acf>", line 1, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection.protos'; 'object_detection' is not a package
```

I've also tried the following and each has resulted in the same error.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/protos')
import pipeline_pb2

from ..protos import pipeline_pb2
```